# Executing epoll_ctl in one thread while the other thread is in the middle of epoll_wait

Tags: multithreading, epoll

I am new to linux server programming with epoll. 
I have 2 threads: Thread_Accept and Thread_epoll. The former is block accept loop, if new connection is coming, it will add the new fd with epoll_ctl(). The latter is a big epoll_wait() loop.

Now my question is: What if when Thread_Accept executing epoll_ctl() while the Thread_epoll is in the middle of epoll_wait? Will it got any side effect?

Thanks in advance.

regards,
Martin

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the epoll_wait man page:

> While one thread is blocked in a call to epoll_pwait(), it is possible for another thread to add a file descriptor to  the  waited-upon  epoll instance. If the new file descriptor becomes ready, it will cause the epoll_wait() call to unblock.

So, no side effects when adding a new file descriptor :-)

(This man page note is the result of the bug mentioned by nathansizemore)

Comment: I cannot believe this wasn't listed as FAQ #1 by the epoll author. One of the main limitations with poll and select is that they are designed for single-threaded use. Changing the monitored descriptors requires silly hoops to wake up the call like signal delivery or using a dummy pipe added to the monitored set, and then callling down again with the whole new fd set.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you make it one thread?

You can set the listener socket to nonblocking and add the socket to your big epoll_wait

Comment: Iwan, I know. But isn't it split to two threads will gain better performance? Just my thinking.

Comment: About gaining better performance, i don't know for sure. In this case, you need to protect every epoll_ctl with locking. IMHO, it will only adding complexity to your code

Answer (score 0):

From [my experience, yes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33885439/epoll-with-edge-triggered-and-oneshot-only-reports-once). But, [this says otherwise](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=43072)

Comment: the link you pointed out in the "this says otherwise" actually agrees with you. You can call epoll_ctl() in thread 1, while thread 2 is epoll_wait()ing, and it'll wake up appropriately when the the fd that was epoll_ctl()ed was available.

Comment: @DannyDulai I was stating that "it will create side effects" (from my experience), but the "this says otherwise" links states that it will not.